# How to add Contract History related list on visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, related-list

How to add Contract History related list on visualforce page?

I have tried:
History,
Histories,
ContractHistories,
ContractHistory,
ServiceContractHistories,
ServiceContractHistory

What is the exact child relationship name for Contract History?

Comment: Thanks Ratan. logs shows Histories as the name. But its still giving error 'Histories' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Contract.

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate, but it's the same basic problem.

Comment: @Ratan, yes field history tracking already enabled.

Comment: @Ratan, yes. i am using apex:relatedlist

Comment: @AnitaBhanarkar the only solution is to query history records and display in vf page. you can't use apex:relatedlist for this history records. check the Martin shared thread